# Symfony 3 - Best practice for concating form-blocks

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to learn how to build forms in symfony 3.
Following some tutorials I have built a PersonType

```
class PersonType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder->add('gender', ChoiceType::class, array('label' => 'Anrede', 'choices' => array('Herr' => 'Herr', 'Frau' => 'Frau'), 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
                ->add('title', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Titel', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
                ->add('firstname', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Vorname', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
                ->add('lastname', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Nachname', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
                ->add('birthdate', DateType::class, array('label' => 'Geburtsdatum', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))

                ->add('street', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Straße', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
                ->add('streetnumber', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Hausnummer', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
                ->add('zip', TextType::class, array('label' => 'PLZ', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
                ->add('city', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Stadt', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))

                ->add('email', TextType::class, array('label' => 'E-Mail', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')));        
        }

    public function getName() {
        return 'person';
        }       

    }
```

And some other types.

In the controller I have

```
$person = new Person();
$form = $this->createForm(PersonType::class, $person);
```

My question now is, how do I now concat the PersonType to some other Types to get one Form out of it? And how do I then set the submit-button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot concatenate but you can include a subset of fields in several forms.

Here you have a nice example in the Symfony documentation :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/inherit_data_option.html

Recap :

- Create a form with your subfields, with the option 'inherit_data' => true.
- Use it in another form as field.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm tryingand searching the web, but when I do the `$resolver->setDefaults(array(
    'inherit_data' => true
    ));` as described, I get a error **Compile Error: Declaration of AppBundle\Form\LocationType::configureOptions() must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface::configureOptions(Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver $resolver)**

Comment: I think you forgot the 'use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;' in your LocationType.php ;)

Comment: actually I got this solved without ´'inherit_data' => true` .. but I had to make the getters&setters in the parent entity.. now it works :) .. thanks dude ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please note how you add fields to `PersonType` form, because it will be exactly the same.

```
->add('email', TextType::class, array('label' => 'E-Mail', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')));
```

What you do here is adding a **subform** `TextType`. It actually contains single field, but it's still a form.

The same way you can add `PersonType` to any other form. That would be something like:

```
->add('person', PersonType::class, array(/* some options if needed*/);
```

> And how do I then set the submit-button?

As mentioned in [Best Practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html#form-button-configuration) for Symfony Forms, I would suggest to add them in template, not to the form object.

Comment: Hi, could you please give a little more information, how to do that? When I try it as you mentioned, Symfony tries and fails to locate the gettes/setters `->add('location', LocationType::class)`

Comment: Well, it's hard to be specific here, because your question is quite broad. Exact solution may vary depending on your case. What I can suggest is to read chapter about forms in Symfony's *The Book*  http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html and other resources like Cookbook or Best practises etc also available on Symfony's page. Then you will have basic knowledge about forms in Symfony's Forms, and you will be able to do much more, and eventually then you can ask a more specific question here on SO.

Comment: When the option 'inherit_data' => true is not specified the form component considere your fields as children of the child 'location'. That works only if your entity contains these children as an embedded class. http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/embeddables.html with the option inherit_data, the children are directrly binded to your person entity.